# c# crossplatform UserControl

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I wonder if it's possible to create some platform-independent UserControls  with Visual Studio or Xamarin. Actually I work on a Windows and Xamarin:Mac (c#) project which both should display a very complex diagram, so it would be extremely helpful if I could code the mathematic once and use it all over the platforms.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Xamarin Forms for this purpose most likely - if there are platform-specific details, you can create a Renderer class for each platform.  Check out the [website](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) for more information.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But if I know it right, Forms is only for iOS, Android and WinPhone. So no MacOS or Windows. But how would a renderer look like for each platform? Also  I want to see the control when dragged onto the designer

Comment: There isn't anything for MacOS but you can make one for Windows using the UWP in Xamarin.

Comment: So this means I cannot do this for Mac AND Windows, only for portable OSs?

Comment: Turns out it looks like you can use it for Mac as well developer.xamarin.com/guides/Mac/getting_started/hello,_mac

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin Forms is available for UWP, MacOS, iOS, Android... The *odds* are you will have to create native renderers on each platform unless you target the drawing via an x-plat package: SkiaSharp, NGraphics, Urhosharp, etc....